# Unable to create persistent volume on AWS using the default storage class in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I'm trying to create persistent volume (PV) on AWS using the persistent volume claim (PVC) and default storage class (of AWS). But PV does not get created on AWS with the default storage class. Not sure if it is an AWS issue (not supporting default storage) or Kubernetes. If I check the status, PV remains in **Pending** state.

Please refer attached screenshot and my manifest file :-

```sh
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
name: sonar-data
spec:
accessModes:
- ReadWriteOnce
storageClassName: default
resources:
requests:
storage: 31Gi
```

Events:-

```sh
vinod827@Vinods-MacBook-Pro ~ % kubectl get pv
No resources found in default namespace.
vinod827@Vinods-MacBook-Pro ~ % kubectl get pvc
NAME               STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
sonar-data         Pending                                      default        79m
sonar-extensions   Pending                                      default        79m
vinod827@Vinods-MacBook-Pro ~ % kubectl describe pvc sonar-data
Name:          sonar-data
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  default
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    sonarqube-6445dc8747-bbktk
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                 From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----                ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  9s (x322 over 80m)  persistentvolume-controller  storageclass.storage.k8s.io "default" not found
vinod827@Vinods-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, most likely not. It depends on how you provisioned your cluster and what your default storage class looks like.

If you are in AWS you might have to create one for [AWS EBS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#aws-ebs) if that's what you would like to use. ❓

You can create any of the other [supported ones too](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner), depending on what you have in your infrastructure.

You can check what you have in your cluster :

```sh
$ kubectl get sc default -o=yaml
```

✌️